# Reset network settings to default (particularly DNS)

Tags: networking, dns, 22.04, wireguard

I have a remote user who switched from Windows to Ubuntu 22.04 and after installing WireGuard and adding the config we provided him, he's having major DNS issues. It's worth noting we have many Linux users in our company using the VPN so I'm really confused as to what initially happened here.

He initially could connect to our (split tunnel) VPN but couldn't reach any resources behind it. We found adding our DNS to his /etc/resolv.conf fixed that temporarily. Then a few days later he randomly couldn't reach anything and our DNS was missing again from his resolv.conf. He had no other DNS entries in his resolv.conf so naturally he couldn't resolve anything. We added entries back and he was able to reach everything.

Today he's again unable to reach anything on the internet. I asked him to reinstall Ubuntu but he already has his dev environments and other things setup and would rather not do all of that again.

At this point I feel like we've poked and prodded and changed so much that I don't think I'm going to be able to resolve the issue when I can't remote into his machine. I've searched for how to reset DNS and networking to defaults but everything I've found appears to be old, or there's so many ways to do it I'm not sure which is best and consistent.

So in conclusion: how do I get this guy's network configuration back to what it was out of the box, so we can start over with his WireGuard config?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, resolv.conf is a symbolic link, not a persistent writable file, as you've seen. I suggest that you add the DNS in Network Manager: https://i.postimg.cc/sfHq9qGP/Screenshot-from-2020-07-08-11-20-54.png Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I asked him to reinstall Ubuntu but he already has his dev environments and other things setup and would rather not do all of that again.

Generally not a good idea but in theory he could reinstall WITHOUT formatting and that would leave settings as is. Far better he fixes the issue at hand.

> I've searched for how to reset DNS and networking to defaults but everything I've found appears to be old, or there's so many ways to do it I'm not sure which is best and consistent.

That should not be needed. `/etc/resolv.conf` is a link that gets its updates from three sources:

- resolvconf (server; command line; often not installed)
- network-manager daemon (desktop; you reset this by removing the connection created by the user)
- DHCP clients (unlikely)

If you do `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` and add a DNS you can test your settings but this will get removed when the user...

- logs out
- restarts the system
- reconnects to the network
- restarts networking service

Using `resolvconf`:

Install if not installed yet with `sudo apt install resolvconf` and create a file:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/nameservers
```

then add a DNS to that file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

(this is a Google DNS; replace by your DNS)

Start and enable it:

```
sudo systemctl start resolvconf.service
sudo systemctl enable resolvconf.service
```

and that should be it.

Network manager from command line (you can do the same in the Network from the desktop):

```
nmcli con
```

will show the name of connection name and this will add google DNS to network manager (replace with own DNS):

```
nmcli con mod {connection} ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
```

Then you can restart it with:

```
nmcli con down {connection}
nmcli con up {connection}
```

After any alteration (resolvconf or networkmanager) you can check  by doing `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Adding them in the network-manager fixed it, and thanks for explaining how resolv.conf works!

Much appreciated!

Comment: cool @murphyslawjr added a command line method for NM